# A custom control with a similar functionality of RadioButton IsChecked property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to understand how the `IsChecked` property in the `RadioButton` works, because I'm building a custom control with have a similar behavior.

The information I need is how a `RadioButton` automatically turns `IsChecked` to `false` when other `RadioButton` is checked.

See the example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Info 1" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton Content="Info 2" />
</StackPanel>
```

If i click in `RadioButton` with `"Info 2"` the other radio will automatically turn to unchecked.

But if the radios is in a diferent `StackPanel` like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Content="Info 1.1" IsChecked="True" />
        <RadioButton Content="Info 1.2" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Content="Info 2.1" IsChecked="True" />
        <RadioButton Content="Info 2.2" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

When the `Info 1.1` is clicked the `Info 2.1` remains checked.

My custom control need this behavior. How is the cleanest way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you can use a solution similar to this: http://www.dragonshed.org/blog/2009/03/08/radiobuttons-in-a-datatemplate-in-silverlight/ EDIT: Also, your last sample code seems contradictory. It sounds like you want all 4 RadioButtons to be linked, but you set `IsChecked=true` for two of them by default.

Answer (score 0):

The RadioButton is a control that is usually used as an item in a group of RadioButton controls.
RadioButton controls inherit from the ToggleButton class, which in turn inherits from ButtonBase. Because RadioButton controls inherit from ToggleButton, they enable a user to change selections.
When RadioButton elements are grouped, the buttons are mutually exclusive. A user can select only one item at a time within a RadioButton group.
In your example radio buttons having content Info 1.1 and Info 1.2  share the same parent control hence
they are grouped which means only 1 radio button is checked at a time while radio buttons having content Info 1.1 and Info 2.1 does not share the same parent control which means they are not grouped
so when Info 1.1 is checked it does not make any effect on Info2.1

Comment: Ok the aspect that group the radios is the Parent Control. But I can't inherit from `ToggleButton`, because is many behaviors that I don't want in my user control.

How I can get all other siblings from `Parent` property?

Comment: Maybe try VisualTreeHelper or LogicalTreeHelper classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can derive your custom control from `RadioButton`. This way, the value of `IsChecked` is toggled whenever you click one of the checkboxes which are grouped with the same parent.